# onPause/onResume in a Unity plugin for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a Unity plugin for an Android SDK. This SDK, in its native form, needs to receive onResume/pause notifications from the app in order to work properly. How can I get notifications for onResume/onPause from inside a Unity plugin?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need an Android Unity plugin for onPause/onResume.

This unity callback is tied to Android's onPause/onResume callbacks.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html

Comment: I already have the plugin. The plugin holds the native SDK which needs those notifications for its work. So I must get those notifications in the plugin or the host app and send them to the SDK. How do I translate MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause to onResume, onPause, onStart, onStop, onRestart?

Comment: In Unity 2017.3.0f3 I'm not always getting calls to OnApplicationPause when my Android Activity is resumed. The official documentation is ambiguous at best.